# Populate listbox using SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am stuck - Im using SQL and want the results to populate in a listbox. I have tried the following:

```
AdvisorOverall = "SELECT TOP 5 tbl_CallLogs.Advisor, Count(tbl_CallLogs.[Date Escalated]) AS [CountOfDate Escalated]" & _
                "FROM tbl_CallLogs" & _
                "GROUP BY tbl_CallLogs.Advisor" & _
                "HAVING (((tbl_CallLogs.Advisor) <> ""))" & _
                "ORDER BY Count(tbl_CallLogs.[Date Escalated]) DESC;"
```

Also tried:

```
me.list3.rowsource = "SELECT TOP 5 tbl_CallLogs.Advisor, Count(tbl_CallLogs.[Date Escalated]) AS [CountOfDate Escalated]" & _
                "FROM tbl_CallLogs" & _
                "GROUP BY tbl_CallLogs.Advisor" & _
                "HAVING (((tbl_CallLogs.Advisor) <> ""))" & _
                "ORDER BY Count(tbl_CallLogs.[Date Escalated]) DESC;"
```

Also tried:

```
me.list3.rowsource = AdvisorOverall
```

Each of the above throw back no error, so unsure where I am going wrong

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Create a query using a GUI (forget the `TOP 5` for now; everything else is doable with the GUI). See what results you get. Once you have it working in the GUI, copy paste the SQL code form there and add the `TOP 5`

Comment: Also, is there a reason you are trying to do this in VBA instead of assigning the `RouSource` in design mode? In VBA you would have to `Requery` the listbox, after setting up the `RowSource` before you see anything change.

Answer (score -1):

Martin Green has some great examples of these kinds of things.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    On Error GoTo UserForm_Initialize_Err
    Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
    cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
             "Data Source=C:\Databases\StaffDatabase.mdb"
    rst.Open "SELECT DISTINCT [Department] FROM tblStaff ORDER BY [Department];", _
             cnn, adOpenStatic
    rst.MoveFirst
    With Me.ComboBox1
        .Clear
        Do
            .AddItem rst![Department]
            rst.MoveNext
        Loop Until rst.EOF
    End With
UserForm_Initialize_Exit:
    On Error Resume Next
    rst.Close
    cnn.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set cnn = Nothing
    Exit Sub
UserForm_Initialize_Err:
    MsgBox Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error!"
    Resume UserForm_Initialize_Exit
End Sub
```

Check out his site here.

http://www.fontstuff.com/vba/